# I am having an issue with a Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Tags: vba

```vb
Sub test()
 Dim c As Long
 For c = 2 To 15000
 Range("E" & c) = WorksheetFunction.Concat(Range("b2:b15000"),Range("a2:a15000"),Range("D" & c))
 Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are combining text from a large number of cells, it may have exceeded the [Total number of characters that a cell can contain 32,767 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).
Try reducing the ranges whose text you combine.